# OpenCV installation Raspberry Pi 3B model

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, opencv3.0

I am trying to install OpenCV in raspberry pi 3B but every time I try to install it gives error during compilation. I have been trying this for a long time and I don't know how to do it. I have followed mainly all the instruction given in these articles :

- [Install opencv 4 on raspberry pi](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi)
- [Install guide raspberry pi 3 raspbian jessie opencv 3](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3)

Comment: Which version do you try to install: opencv 3 or 4 ? Which error do you get printed ? Which version of raspbian ? Steps to reproduce the error ?

Comment: I have tried installing both the version of OpenCV, I am using Raspian Buster for desktop and the error I am getting is `[ 43%] Built target opencv_test_core
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2`

Comment: Edit your answer with all these details ? What's after `[ 43%] Built target opencv_test_core make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2` ?

Comment: For now I am trying to install opencv-3.4.4 and the error I am getting is this is different every time one such is this c++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault signal terminated program cc1plus and make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2 and again I am using Raspian-3.1 and this error happens when I use make -j4 command in terminal, is this enough ?

Comment: Steps to reproduce ?

Comment: The steps given in the above links mentioned are the steps that I followed more then half command works fine but error is given in encountered after using the make -j4 command

Comment: try with `make` instead, the -j4 parameter must be the culprit

Comment: I have tried with that also it still gives error at some point

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error a few weeks ago and for me it works when I just use

```
make -j
```

instead of

```
make -j4
```

-j4 simply means that the raspberry pi uses all for cpu cores instead of just one with make -j

Hope I could help and please write if that works for you as well ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Michael, I even tried doing that but i couldn't get it done. At last I dropped the idea of using raspberry pi.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any new ideas two. I can recommend this awesome tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OjeurIpmB1M
this works at least for me